# Searching for a particular trading platform

Tags: currency, trading, cryptocurrency, forex

I'm trying to find an "Exchange/trading platform" with the following conditions

- I must be able to purchase currencies (fiat or crypto) and not need to return back to the base currency. I do not wish to open and close positions. I plan to only take, never make. - *Is there a name for this?*
- The commission needs to be as low as possible preferably less than 0.1% per trade (I want to high-frequency trade)
- I'm after API access for the High-frequency trading.
- I'm after a large grid/table (every currency into every other currency) for example:

[image]

Ideally, 9+ currencies. - I have made this in excel using modified data from https://www.exchangerates.org.uk/currency/currency-exchange-rates-table.html

If all of these exist on a single website, that would be wonderful!

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Comment: It's tough competition in the HFT space, good luck!

Comment: For cryptos almost any exchange fits your requirements. And most of them have open API.
But for fiat currencies retail trader is limited to leveraged positions with FX brokers or futures (you have to open/close position using your terminology).
Some banks may allow you to exchange currencies but there will no low rates and HFT.

Comment: @Yuri Ginsberg I don’t know of any with a complete grid larger than 9x9. Binnacle offers a 6x6 grid and poloniex offers a 5x5 grid.

Comment: I spoke only about non leveraged trading and open API. I agree that it is really hard (if possible at all) to find an exchange that has 9 currencies which are both base and quote.

Comment: @Yuri Ginsburg Is non leveraged trading the name for purchasing a currency? I’ve heard the term spot trading, but I’m not sure how that fits in. I know leveraged is say 50:1 and non leveraged is always 1:1

Comment: Try Bitfinex. They have 100+ wallets, so probably you can find 9+ pairs to trade.

Answer (score -1):

`Binance.com` (crypto) has what you want.

API Access: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs

Low Fees: 0.075% for a taker trade

If you use my referral link you will get an additional permanent 10% trading fee reduction.

https://www.binance.com/en/register?ref=OTWO00WS

(I also get 10% so it's a win win)

Comment: Binance only has a 6x6 using BNB, BTC, ETH, TRX, XRP, USDT

Comment: @BenCrossley Are you wanting to trade arbitrage using linear algebra on this matrix?

Comment: Ok, why is it you need 9+ bases? For arbitrage, you only need 2.

Comment: my method has very low computational complexity but very high primary calculation times. So it only becomes a viable method when there is a large enough grid to beat other methods. I roughly worked out that 8x8 is the break-even point, so 9x9 upwards would make my method faster.

Comment: I doubt there is anywhere that provides data in a matrix so if your bottleneck is creating this matrix then I would recommend trying some alternate methods.

Comment: I don't require the data to be in a matrix format, merely that the data exists. I can populate the array myself. I was doing this on OANDA before I released I could only open and close positions. If I could actually exchange currencies rather than always cashing in in some base currency then OANDa would have been perfect.